# How to have users sign transactions on an ethereum based platform without giving up their Private Keys to the platform?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, private-key

How to have users sign transactions on an ethereum based platform without surrendering their Private Keys to the platform?

Need the process to be automated, while users not giving up their private keys to the platform.

Comment: Dear @LauriPeltonen thanks a lot for the response. The only issue is that the signing of the transaction has to be automated, where various wallets have to sign transactions (order) coming through the platform without giving up their private keys...otherwise (if signing done manual), the platform's operations will not run smoothly and orders will be queued.

Answer (score 1):

What your describing can be achieved with signing transactions offline (or at least outside the platform).

The process works like this:

1) A raw transaction is prepared by someone (the platform). This includes all the information required for the transaction except the private key part.

2) The raw transaction is given to the private key holder (user)

3) The user signs the given transaction with his private key and the transaction is ready. It can either be given back to the platform to be published or it can be published by some other means.

You can find plenty of tutorials about how to sign transactions (offline) without revealing the private key. You can also use various tools to do it. Here's one example of how it can be done: https://tokenmarket.net/news/technology/creating-offline-ethereum-transactions-in-javascript/

Comment: thanks for the response. The only issue is that the signing of the transaction has to be automated where various wallets have to sign transactions (orders) coming through the platform without giving up their private keys to the platform..otherwise (if signing done manual), the platform's operations will not run smoothly and orders will be queued till the wallet owner signs it. Kindly note that it is mutually agreed between the platform and the wallet owner that the tokens in this specific wallet are kept there for the sole purpose of being offered via the platform @ a spot price

Comment: Surely you can create a system where the platform sends a signing request to the use and some user's system receives it and signs the given transaction automatically.